# Where do we call 'Shm_unlink()'

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory

i have been working on shared memory in linux.
1 producer process and 3 consumer process in c++.
The producer process creates the shared memory via 'shm_open()' call.

The 3 consumer process reads the data from shared memory.

Could you please suggest me to best solution to delete shared memory after reading all data by the  consumer process.?

how do we know process is still reading from shared memory?

Comment: You may like to describe your problem in more detail to get better advice. What kind of interaction is there between the producer and consumers? What kind of data the shared file holds?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is that the producer must know the number of consumers in advance. Otherwise, there is no way to know when and how many processes will want to open the file in the future, so that you never know when it is safe to remove the file.

The producer stores an integer number of expected consumers in the shared file. After mapping the file with `MAP_SHARED` each consumer atomically decrements that integer and when it reaches 0 the file can be unlinked.

Note that the file can be unliked right after opening it. Unlinking removes the filename from the filesystem, the file content isn't deleted until the last user of the file closes and/or unmaps it.

---

Alternatively, have a cronjob that removes files older then specified duration.

Comment: Is there notification mechanism to indicate the producer?

Comment: @sumith There is https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: @sumith What do you want to notify the producer about?

Comment: The producer creates the shared memory and writes data to it. the consumer reads data from shared memory. if the producer call 'shm_unlink()', during the read.then the consumer process not able to read data. The producer doesn't know how many process use the shared memory.  i wish the producer deletes the shared memory only after all read by the consumers.

Comment: @sumith Your problem as described is best solved by producer writing into a regular file.